# Are large meteor craters possible with the survival of most human society?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, natural-disasters, meteor

In my world, I am looking for a crater formed by a meteor impact that deposited a large number of resources there. The final crater should be 200 miles in diameter. I would like to do this with minimal effects on the rest of society. The meteor, however, would be made of a material that doesn't necessarily have to be rock or ice or iron; it has many mystical properties. The site of the impact is uninhabited and the nearest civilization is across a body of water 2000 miles away. My question is, using this material, is it possible for such a large crater to form without extinguishing human civilization? Feel free to make up any properties of the meteor that make it easier for the crater to form and/or keep civilization intact.

I've used two impact simulators: the Earth Impact Effects Program with my hypothetical inputs [here](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/cgi-bin/crater.cgi?dist=2000&distanceUnits=2&diam=25000&diameterUnits=1&pdens=&pdens_select=1500&vel=51&velocityUnits=1&theta=45&wdepth=&wdepthUnits=1&tdens=2500) - (most of the inputs are guessed based on the program's guidelines in order to create a crater large enough) - and the [Asteroid Collision Map](https://asteroidcollision.herokuapp.com), where the biggest preset for meteor diameter, 15000 m, shows worldwide fallout. For the Earth Impact Effects Program (which I'm assuming is more accurate because it is created by two major universities), it shows an earthquake at 11 on the Richter scale, larger than any ever recorded, so the scenario seems pretty much impossible with conventional meteors.

Comment: To put this in perspective: you're doubling the size of the crater formed by the meteor that caused the [Cretaceous-Paleogene extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event) that wiped out 75% of all life on Earth.

Comment: "Most" of human civilization would not survive such an impact, but some will survive, building a new civilization after an apocalyptic period.

Comment: *The meteor ... has many mystical properties*  This is just bolt on magic and completely negates the [tag:reality-check] and [tag:science-based] tags you have on your question.  With arbitrary mystical properties you can do whatever you want, so what's the point of the question ?

Answer (score 4):

**Your meteor hit 65 million years ago.**

Mess stuff up it did.  But stuff then got its stuff back together over the millennia.  The ancestors of humans had a hard time to be sure. By the time humans were on the scene, the meteor was covered in layers of sediment, and a forest.

But it is down there.  And whatever resources it brought are down there with it.

Isn't this the Wakanda / Vibranium thing?  The vibranium meteor was there a long time before humans, and the Wakandans more or less lucked into it.